# Rust. Перегрузка операторов для пользовательского типа данных

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, rust

Я хотел написать небольшой код на rust`e но столкнулся с некоторыми трудностями. Я сделал struct Vector с тремя полями одного типа и для него мне нужно перегрузить операторы сложения, вычитания и умножения. Попытка перегрузить оператор сложения не удалась, хотя я все делал по примерам из книг и интернета. Вот сам код:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Vector<T> {
    x1: T,
    x2: T,
    x3: T,
}

impl<T> Add<T> for Vector<T>
{
    type Output = Vector<T>;
    
    fn add(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector {x1: self.x1 + rhs.x1, x2: self.x2 + rhs.x2, x3: self.x3 + rhs.x3};
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vector1 = Vector { x1: 5.6, x2: 7.2, x3: 2.5 };
    let vector2 = Vector { x1: -0.1, x2: 10.9, x3: 3.3 };
    println!("Вектор 1: ({}, {}, {})", vector1.x1, vector1.x2, vector1.x3);
    println!("Вектор 2: ({}, {}, {})", vector2.x1, vector2.x2, vector2.x3);
    let vector3 = vector1 + vector2;
    println!("Сумма векторов: ({}, {}, {})", vector3.x1, vector3.x2, vector3.x3);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
    error[E0053]: method `add` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> main.rs:13:5
   |
13 | /     fn add(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
14 | |         Vector {x1: self.x1 + rhs.x1, x2: self.x2 + rhs.x2, x3: self.x3 + rhs.x3};
15 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected type parameter, found struct `Vector`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(Vector<T>, T) -> Vector<T>`
              found type `fn(Vector<T>, Vector<T>) -> Vector<T>`

error: aborting due to previous error(s)
```

Писал и компилировал в онлайн компиляторе. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросал вам полный пример с исправлением ваших ошибок.

**Код:**

```rust
use core::ops::Mul;
use core::ops::Sub;
use std::ops::Add;

struct Vector<T> {
    x1: T,
    x2: T,
    x3: T,
}


/* сложение */
/* ошибка в Add<T> */
/* вы указали добавить тип T, хотя явно желали Vector<T> */
/* поэтому Add<T> -> Add<Vector<T>>*/

/* советую читать онлайн документацию */
// https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html
impl<T> Add</*T*/ Vector<T>> for Vector<T> where T: Add<Output = T> /* мы описали where для того чтобы любой T внутри функции можно было сложить с T*/ {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    fn add(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector {
            x1: self.x1 + rhs.x1, /* у вас любой тип T, не обязательно у типа данных */
            x2: self.x2 + rhs.x2, /* T есть сложение, опишите это в where !! */
            x3: self.x3 + rhs.x3
        } //; ошибка, вы хотите вернуть значение (используйте return или опустите знак ;)
    }
}

// вычитание
// https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Sub.html
impl<T> Sub<Vector<T>> for Vector<T> where T: Sub<Output = T> /* мы описали where для того чтобы любой T внутри функции можно было вычесть с T*/ {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    fn sub(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector {
            x1: self.x1 - rhs.x1,
            x2: self.x2 - rhs.x2,
            x3: self.x3 - rhs.x3
        } 
    }
}

// умножение
// https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html
impl<T> Mul<Vector<T>> for Vector<T> where T: Mul<Output = T> /* мы описали where для того чтобы любой T внутри функции можно было умножить с T*/ {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector {
            x1: self.x1 * rhs.x1,
            x2: self.x2 * rhs.x2,
            x3: self.x3 * rhs.x3
        } 
    }
}




/* все операторы сложения, умножения, ...*/
/* можно получить по пути */
/* https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html */

fn main() {
    /* сумма */
    let vector1 = Vector { x1: 5.6, x2: 7.2, x3: 2.5 };
    let vector2 = Vector { x1: -0.1, x2: 10.9, x3: 3.3 };
    let vector3 = vector1 + vector2;
    println!("Сумма векторов: ({}, {}, {})", vector3.x1, vector3.x2, vector3.x3);
    
    
    /* разница */
    let vector1 = Vector { x1: 5.6, x2: 7.2, x3: 2.5 };
    let vector2 = Vector { x1: -0.1, x2: 10.9, x3: 3.3 };
    let vector4 = vector1 - vector2;
    println!("Разница векторов: ({}, {}, {})", vector4.x1, vector4.x2, vector4.x3);
    
    /* умножение */
    let vector1 = Vector { x1: 5.6, x2: 7.2, x3: 2.5 };
    let vector2 = Vector { x1: -0.1, x2: 10.9, x3: 3.3 };
    let vector4 = vector1 * vector2;
    println!("Умножение векторов: ({}, {}, {})", vector4.x1, vector4.x2, vector4.x3);
    
    /*
        Сумма векторов: (5.5, 18.1, 5.8)
        Разница векторов: (5.699999999999999, -3.7, -0.7999999999999998)
        Умножение векторов: (-0.5599999999999999, 78.48, 8.25)
    */
}
```

**Советы:**

1. В расте придерживайтесь общего стиля введения кода (Вы начали прямо как в си раскидывать '{' на новой строке).
2. Читайте дополнительно онлайн документацию https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html
3. По расту достаточно книг для новичков.
4. Есть официальное русское сообщество для новичков по расту в телеге (https://t.me/rust_beginners_ru).

/*дополнено*/

5. Поставьте VsCode IDE с плагином Rust, не пишите в онлайне.

***Вперёд!***

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```rust
impl<T: Add<Output = T>> Add<Vector<T>> for Vector<T> {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    fn add(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector {
            x1: self.x1 + rhs.x1,
            x2: self.x2 + rhs.x2,
            x3: self.x3 + rhs.x3,
        }
    }
}
```